My HestiaCP File manager is not working and throwing an unknown error message
My HestiaCP (Hestia Control Panel) File manager is not working. It's throwing an Unknown error message.


Among the features of HestiaCP, the option to manage web spaces stands out, choose between different versions of PHP, FTP, DNS, mail server, databases, local and remote backups.
In addition, it comes configured with Apache2 and Nginx as a proxy, which makes the websites go much faster. It also includes the option to add free SSL certificates thanks to Let's Encrypt in an automated way.
When you create a new machine with HestiaCP, you must keep in mind that the server is almost instantaneous but then it will take around 15 minutes to install all the components of the panel. Therefore, at the time of receiving the email with the server password, the panel will not yet be accessible from the browser.
After a few minutes of installing the HestiaCP panel, you will be able to access the HestiaCP server from a browser by entering the server IP along with port 8083.
It is important that after installing HestiaCP you take the following steps to avoid problems in the future.
The first thing you need to do is change the email address of the admin account. By default it is admin@changeme.local and this email does not exist; it is an example. What you need to do is add your email address to avoid problems with Let's Encrypt and receive notifications from the panel.
To change it you need to click on Edit User (Pencil) within the panel.
Then you need to change the email address to a valid one.
Another thing you need to change is the server hostname. This will avoid SPAM problems, since the default server name does not exist either and if emails are sent with this hostname these emails will surely be detected as SPAM.
Click on Server (Gear) at the top left of the panel.
Then click on Configure.
Here you will change the Server name (Hostname) by displaying the basic options section to a domain name that exists on the server and has a DNS record for it.
